# How to stick tabs from content to top of screen while scrolling in android

Tags: android, android-layout, sticky, android-tablayout

I have Working on a layout in which my TabLayout is between some content and should be sticked to top ( below Toolbar) on reaching top while scrolling.
Following is my layout xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <com.sample.retail.ui.view.StickyScrollView
            android:id="@+id/sticky_scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:stuckShadowDrawable="@drawable/sticky_shadow_default">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:elevation="@dimen/home_activity_views_elevation"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/home_top_banner_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/home_banner_layout_height">

                    <com.sample.retail.ui.view.viewPager.ScrollerViewPager
                        android:id="@+id/home_banner_view_pager"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:elevation="@dimen/home_activity_views_elevation" />

                    <com.Sample.retail.ui.view.viewPager.SpringTabIndicator
                        android:id="@+id/home_banner_indicator"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/home_banner_indicator_width"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_banner_indicator_height"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/home_banner_view_pager"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:elevation="12dp"
                        app:stiIndicatorColor="@color/theme_primary"
                        app:stiIndicatorColors="@array/spring_indicator_colors"
                        app:stiRadiusMax="4dp"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/home_activity_views_elevation">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/home_category_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_category_layout_height"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cat_textView1"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.25"
                            android:background="@drawable/grey_ripple"
                            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_wallet_giftcard"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Fashion" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cat_textView2"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.25"
                            android:background="@drawable/grey_ripple"
                            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_phone"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Electronics" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cat_textView3"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.25"
                            android:background="@drawable/grey_ripple"
                            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_phone"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Sports" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/cat_textView4"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="0.25"
                            android:background="@drawable/grey_ripple"
                            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_list_2"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:text="Categories" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    card_view:cardElevation="@dimen/home_activity_views_elevation">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/home_lower_banner_layout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/home_lower_banner_height"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/lower_banner_firstImageView"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight=".50"
                            android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_strike_thru"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/banner3" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/lower_banner_secondImageView"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight=".50"
                            android:background="@drawable/shape_bg_strike_thru"
                            android:scaleType="fitXY"
                            android:src="@drawable/banner4" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/recently_viewed_text_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/home_view_headertext_layout_height"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:background="#66000000"
                    android:elevation="@dimen/home_activity_views_elevation"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/recently_viewed_item_textView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/recently_viewed"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/home_section_header_textSize"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>  


                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/categoryTabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/theme_primary"
                    android:tag="sticky"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:theme="@style/AppTabTheme" />

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/product_viewpager"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </com.sample.retail.ui.view.StickyScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I have also tried StickyItemView https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyScrollViewItems/issues/27 Library  as  above but its not gonna work for me as Its pretty hard for me to redirects touch and motion Events between stickked views like TabLayout. I Will use Recycler view in ViewPager below Tabs.How do I achieve this  on scroll sticking things of TabLayout? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a answer by working around it a bit more. Following is my trick working  for me.

```
<Coodinatorlayout   
    <Appbarlaout -- with marginTop=height of toobar
        <View> --with android:layout_scrollFlags = "scroll"
        <View> --with android:layout_scrollFlags = "scroll"
        <View> --with android:layout_scrollFlags = "scroll"
        <View> --with android:layout_scrollFlags = "scroll"
        <View> --with android:layout_scrollFlags = "scroll"
        .....
        ....
        <View> --with android:layout_scrollFlags = "scroll"
        <TabLayout>--with android:layout_scrollFlags = "scroll|exitUnitlCollapsed|"
    </Appbarlayout>
    <Viewpager>  --with app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

 <Toobar>  --with gravity top  //this is the main trick part. Put a separate toolbar in parent coordinate layout instead of putting it in AppbarLayout. and set this as support Action bar
</Coordinatorlayout>
```

Comment: Instead of `android` namespace must use `app`

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand what you are trying to do is have at the top some static tabs and at the bottom of it some recyclerview? Then you don't need to encapsulate the recyclerview with a scrollview since recyclerview comes with its own scrolling. Can you post an image of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi user912010, thanks for reply. I want  to make a sample retail app Home activity layout design. In which I am  trying to put some banners and content on top and then a  TabLayout for categories attached with a view pager with it. Tabs should be changed or horizontal scrolling of view pager . I want to scroll the content vertically but Tabs should be sticked to top while scrolling  products in View pager fragment  should be continue. Just like Twitter Profile Activity But some more content between tabs and Actionbar as above.